# show that $y'=f(y)$ has one solution only, $f(y)=-y\ln y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> let $f(y)=-y\ln y$ if $0<y<1$ and $f(y)=0$ otherwise
>
> prove that $y'=f(y)$ has only one solution such that $y(0)=c$

I guess $c$ is a fixed arbitrary constant.

it's easy to see that $f$ is non negative, so the solution $y$ must be increasing.

despite this wolfram alpha says that $y(x)=e^{e^{-x+c}}$ is a solution to differential equation somewhere, but this is decreasing!

what am I missing?

how can I solve this problem?

I tried proving that $f$ satisfies the lipschitz condition, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: You have not managed to convey to Wolfram Alpha that $f(y) = 0$ for $y \geqslant 1$. The solution given by WA has $y(x) > 1$, and there $-y\ln y < 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you. that explains it. any hint on how can I prove what is asked?

Comment: Since $f$ locally satisfies a Lipschitz condition except at $0$, the solutions are unique except possibly a solution that is zero on some interval and nonzero on another. Solve the differential equation to see that a solution that is nonzero anywhere is nonzero always.

Comment: @DanielFischer I forgot to say I was unable to prove that $f$ is a lipschitz function on $0<y<1$

Comment: It's not. But it's Lipschitz on $[\varepsilon,\infty)$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$. That's sufficient.

Comment: @DanielFischer shouldn't I be wanting uniqueness on an interval containing $0$? if I can prove that $f$ is lipschitz, I still have a hard time following your instructions. does lipschitz condition guarantee the existence of a solution? by the way thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $c$ is in $(0,1)$, $f(y(0))\ne0$ hence, at least in a neighborhood $(-t_0,t_0)$ of $0$, $y'/f(y)=1$. Since $y'/f(y)=(-\ln\ln y)'$, this yields $\ln\ln y(t)=-t+\ln\ln y(0)=-t+\ln\ln c$ on $(-t_0,t_0)$, that is, $y(t)=c^{\exp(-t)}$.

For every $c$ in $(0,1)$, $y_c:t\mapsto c^{\exp(-t)}$ is defined on the whole real line, hence the maximal solution with initial condition $y(0)=c$ is $y=y_c$, defined on the whole real line. Note that $t\mapsto\mathrm e^{-t}$ is decreasing and $c\lt1$ hence $y_c$ is increasing on the whole real line.

In the general case, assume that there exists a nonzero maximal solution $\bar y$ starting from $\bar y(0)=c$. Then, $f(\bar y(s))\ne0$ at least for some $s$ hence $\bar y(s)$ is in $(0,1)$. Thus, the function $y:t\mapsto\bar y(s+t)$ solves the differential equation $y'=f(y)$ with initial condition $y(0)=\bar y(s)$. The study above shows that $y(t)=y(0)^{\exp(-t)}$, that is, $\bar y(s+t)={\bar y(s)}^{\exp(-t)}$ for every $t$ in the real line. Hence $c=\bar y(0)={\bar y(s)}^{\exp(s)}$. Since $\bar y(s)$ is in $(0,1)$ and $\exp(s)\gt0$, $c$ is in $(0,1)$.

Finally, if some nonzero solution exists, then $c$ is in $(0,1)$.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I don't undertsand why $f(y(0))=0\implies y(t)=0$ for every $t\ge 0$.

Comment: if I understood correctly, you just gave me existence. how I get uniqueness?

Comment: See revised version.

Comment: Thanks *to you* for insisting after the first version of my answer (and +1 to the question).